# neo4j REST LDAP security

Tags: security, rest, ldap, jetty, neo4j

How to make acces to neo4j REST standalone server by LDAP? By default, there is no any security things in neo4j. In my opinion, i should run Apache Http server over neo4j, which use jetty inside. But I also know, that jetty can do LDAP, but it is part of neo4j, so its hard to configure. Wich way should I go?

Answer (score 2):

Right now I think there are two possibilities. The first, as you mention, is to front Neo4j with Apache and let Apache take on the security workload.

The other is much more invasive, and that's to write a filter for JAX-RS (or a servlet filter) and get that registered with Jersey. If you're comfortable with hacking a bit of code, the second gives you a single box solution.